# Three js hdr turns off but never back on

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to turn on and off a hdr map in three js.

This is how I create it

```
//HDRI LOADER
var envmaploader = new THREE.PMREMGenerator(renderer);
const loadhdri = new THREE.RGBELoader()
.load("myhdr.hdr", function (texture){
 texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
scene.background = texture;
scene.environment = texture;
```

})

So far so good.

I then add it to the gui:

```
var gui = new dat.gui.GUI();
  var params = {switch: true}
  const lightsFolder = gui.addFolder('Customize lights')
  lightsFolder.add(params, "switch").name('hdrenv').onChange(updateHdr)
```

Finally, I try to specify the on/off logic, but when I read the console logs, it's always printing 'false'

```
function updateHdr() {
if (params2==true)
   {
   scene.environment = texture
   console.log("true")}
    else
   {scene.environment = null
   console.log ("else switch false")
   }
}
```

Note that the hdr loads correctly, turns off correctly when I click the switch button, but never turns on again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write your `updateHdr` function like so:

```js
function updateHdr( value ) {

    if ( value === true ) {

        scene.environment = texture;
        console.log( 'true' );

    } else {

        scene.environment = null;
        console.log( 'else switch false' );

    }

}
```